# Different versions of API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

The structure to the example on http://apiblueprint.org/#get-started seems to differ from the structure on APIary.io.

Can anyone please comment on whether they are different, and if so, which structure is correct?

For example,

API Blueprint Document Structure

1.) Metadata 
2.) API Name & Overview 
3.) Resource 
A.) URI Parameters 
B.) Model 
1.) Headers 
2.) Body 
3.) Schema 
C.) Action 
1.) URI Parameters 
2.) Request 
a.) Headers 
b.) Body 
c.) Schema 
3.) Response 
a.) Headers 
b.) Body 
c.) Schema
4.) Resource Group 
A.) Resource

versus

```
{
    "_version": "2.0",
    "metadata": [],
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "resourceGroups": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "description": "",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "uriTemplate": "/message",
                    "model": {},
                    "parameters": [],
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "name": "",
                            "description": "",
                            "method": "GET",
                            "parameters": [],
                            "examples": [
                                {
                                    "name": "",
                                    "description": "",
                                    "requests": [],
                                    "responses": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "200",
                                            "description": "",
                                            "headers": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Content-Type",
                                                    "value": "text/plain"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "body": "Hello World!\n",
                                            "schema": ""
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The "API Blueprint Document Structure" you mentioned is how you write an API Blueprint document.

The JSON you wrote above is the AST that you get when you parse the above API Blueprint using the API Blueprint parser like https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash.

So, both of them represent your API Blueprint correctly, but the non-AST one is much more readable.

Hope that clears your confusion.